# Custom DateTime stringformat in WPF

Tags: wpf, datetime, binding, string-formatting

I can't get my custom DateTime string format to work in my binding.  I want the format to be "mmmm, yyyy" (e.g. "June, 2012").

The following does not work.  I get a short date format (m/d/yyyy).

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow,
                          Path=Date,
                          StringFormat={}{0:MMMM\, yyyy}"/>
```

I've considered using a converter, but I prefer a pure XAML approach.

**Edit:**

For clarity, I have a `Window` with a dependency property `Date` of type `DateTime`.  In my XAML, I've named the window 'Thiswindow'.

**Edit 2:**

I looked back at my actual code, and I had a `Label`, not a `TextBlock`.  I changed it to TextBlock and it works fine.

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=ThisWindow,
                 Path=Date,
                 StringFormat={}{0:MMMM\, yyyy}"/>
```

Anyone know why it doesn't work with `Label`?

Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me (except it should be `{0:MMMM\, yyyy}`).  Something about your "Date" property?  Is it by chance returning a `string` instead of a `DateTime`?

Comment: I'll edit to make the situation clearer...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ContentControls` have a [`ContentStringFormat` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.contentstringformat.aspx) which overrides the original formatting.

(When i saw your question i expected this to be the problem actually but was surprised to find a `TextBlock` at first)

Answer (score 2):

Your month needs to be in uppercase:

```
{Binding Source={x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}, StringFormat={}{0:MMMM\, yyyy}}
```

EDIT:

The Label problem is probably because Label has Content, not Text.

Change the Text="{Binding ...}" to Content="{Binding ...}"

Comment: I had it as a `Content` property when it was a `Label`, and it wasn't working.